# can't stop autoplay on youtube embedded videos in slider

Tags: html, wordpress, youtube, embed

There is plenty of information on this and the fix of setting autoplay or autostart to false seems simple.

Only it doesn't work for me at all, have tried every combination can think of.

I am embedding video in layer slider slide in wordpress and the video playing is stopping slide from transition to the next one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Below are some examples of various ways I've tried to make it work. It is the same issue on chrome as on safari, and mobile

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PhCLPGg2WOM?autoplay=0” frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=“></iframe>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PhCLPGg2WOM?autoplay=false" type="audio/mpeg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tUJJv0EZSuI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen autoplay="0" autostart="0" type="audio/mpeg"></iframe>
```

Comment: Below? I don’t see anything …

Comment: dang. Somehow deleted the code block when I edited at nearly 1am - attention to detail deficit

Comment: is you want to stop the video in case of click on next button?

Comment: @jewfro What plugin are you using for slider? Using LayerSlider plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Go to slider settings, and turn off the autoplay mode under "Video" section. since it is not working on the code it self. Check the link given below, will be useful.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/stopping-autoplay-on-iframe-videos/

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research on your problem, however I don't personally have a WordPress premium account of which I can test. So, what I do know is that your disable auto-play code does work on Chrome in a normal HTML setting. I found this link that might help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26QOdyxeYfY

However, it looks like you might have already tried that solution. I have also found another link (http://www.kriesi.at/support/topic/layerslider-youtube-video-autoplay-issue/) that says that the LayerSlider plugin has its own auto play settings under Slider Settings>video.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The Layer Slider plugin has its own slider settings for each slider. Go to the Slider Settings > videos, and under videos tab turn off the Automatically play videos options.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the slider then go to Global Settings. Go to Slideshow panel and turn off “Automatically play videos” option.

Answer (score 0):

Remove autoplay=0 and try it out in your embed url at the end there is autoplay=0 or other numbers remove it and try it out